# Character casing in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hello I have following code section

```
<select id="ddlSite" ng-model="area.siteId"><option >Select</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in sites" value="{{item.siteId}}">{{item.siteId}}-{{item.code}}</option>
</select>
```

Here a class Sites which have two property named as : SiteId and Code
When we bind drop down code working fine and dropdown display value.

**But if change code as below from above code section:**

```
 <select id="ddlSite" ng-model="area.siteId">
 <option >Select</option>
 <option ng-repeat="item in sites" value="{{item.siteid}}">{{item.siteid}}-{{item.code}}</option>
 </select>
```

see here "I" is in `{{item.siteid}}` small casing  and drop down display blank value.

what may be issue even `{{item.code}}` OR `{{item.Code}}` both are working.
please help....

Comment: may be your `sites` object is having both code and Code keys, that is the reason why it's not throwing any error in the latter part.

Comment: Yes, there is strong case sensitivity in Angular (because in Javascript itself) so `a.B` and `a.b` are two different variables. If it is working with `code` and `Code` it means both variables actually exist (which may be a bug you want to have a look at)

Comment: No there is only Code property not code
-Result as below return from DAL:  
-{Smart.DataModel.Site} Smart.DataModel.Site

  Code 
  Description
  ModifiedBy 
  ModifiedDate
  Name 
  Notes 
  SiteId   Status

Comment: I think this is due to data type of property. SiteId is type of "Int" and Code is type of string.

Comment: Don't think the type matter.  Just make sure whatever is in the JSON that your server side  model return is the same casing you use in the binding (unless you are doing some sort of conversion / mapping in between that change the cases).  If it is Code, then it should be Code on client side as well.  Don't assume that code work it will work... that itself is kind of strange.

Comment: To debug, after you get the data back from the server, do a `$log.debug` on it and see what the shape and casing of it in the console window.

Comment: Can you put in html {{ sites | json }} or enter in console in debug mode and get out variable sites and bring us to see what is under the hood?